# Redirection best practice to deploy a react application behind a redirection server

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, gateway

I've deploy a react application with this protocol:

**1- build from local api:**

> npm run build:preprod

**2- put the build folder into a server folder**

**3- start the application:**

> pm2 serve build 3000 --name "myApplication" --spa

the application run perfectly if I check http://myapi:3000

The problem is that I've setted a redirection from another server (to benefit from its certificate and from a "same-origin" with the back application.

**So normally, here is the result:**

> https://server-preprod/myapplication

REDIRECT TO

> http://myapi:3000

But this redirection doesn't work:
1- the root folder of the api react is finded - status 200
2- all files called with it are 404 error due to a bad redirection

In fact, to find a simple chunk.css, instead of :

> https://server-preprod/myapplication/static/chunk.css

It misses an url fragment:

> https://server-preprod/static/chunk.css

The url https://server-preprod/myapplication/ is generate by the redirection server like I said before, so I don't understand how it appends and how I can resolve this problem

EDIT :
So, I've set an homepage in package.json like this :

> "homepage": "https://server-preprod/myapplication",

and now, the css and the js files seems to be called from the good adress but I've an error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

The code is exactly the same and I absolutely don't know why I have this error...

Comment: I've edited my message. I've setted an "homepage" variable in package.json but now I've a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" error...